# Why is it possible to use File class in build.gradle without importing java.io.File?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In build.gradle files you can use File directly like

```java
def file = new File("file.txt")
```

And even if you import java.io.File manually [ide says it's unused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCjd9.png)

But at the same time ide says that [File is java.io.File class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhFAO.png)

I wonder what approach was used to achieve this behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is feature of Groovy language itself as it imports some java packages by default without needing to specify it:
https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_default_imports

Answer (score 0):

Gradle builds on the standard java File class, so there is no need to import.

quote from docs:

> In order to perform some action on a file, you need to know where it is, and that’s the information provided by file paths. Gradle builds on the standard Java File class, which represents the location of a single file, and provides new APIs for dealing with collections of paths.

More information, Check [Working with Files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:locating_files) at gradle official docs.

Comment: does this mean that File class is included in the gradle jar?

Comment: As much as I know, Yes. Gradle has the java File class included.